# Como transformar arquivo em excel em list? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como posso transformar o arquivo em excel em list depois de lê-lo

df = pd.read_excel('Dados.xlsx')

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/)...
O seu código vai ficar parecido com o abaixo:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('teste.xls') #Use o nome do seu arquivo
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Planilha1') #Use o nome da aba do seu arquivo
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

lista = []  # Cria a lista vazia
for i in range(worksheet.nrows): 
    valor = worksheet.cell_value(i, 0) # Pega os valores do excel
    lista.append(valor) # Insere os valores na lista

print(lista)
```

- Voce pode utilizar a biblioteca xlrd para ler o arquivo.
- Crie uma lista vazia
- Use **append** para incluir itens na sua lista

Lembre-se que com este código voce pegará inclusive o valor da primeira linha. Modifique seu código para o que voce precisa.